# Does WPF allow casting a data grid to type visual?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, grid

I have a data grid in WPF as shown below . I need to pass this as an object of Type Visual class in the code behind . Is that possible in WPF

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `DataGrid` is a `Visual` so you only need to assign the element an `x:Name` in your XAML markup:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="dg" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" AutoGenerateColumns="False" > 
...
```

You could then refer to it using this name in the code-behind as the XAML compiler creates a backing field for you:

```
Visual v = dg;
```

Comment: Is there any documentation on this that I can read more about

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop-wpf/xaml-services/xname-directive

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can.

Xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApp1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp1"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <DataGrid  x:Name="MyGrid" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" AutoGenerateColumns="False" Grid.Row="1">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Image" Width="SizeToCells" IsReadOnly="True">
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Image Source="{Binding Image}" />
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
        <Grid.Background>
            <VisualBrush Visual="{Binding Visual}"/>
        </Grid.Background>

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

And here is what you can do in the backend code. Simplay assign the control to Visual.

```
    public class VM
    {
        public Visual Visual { get; set; }
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            DataContext = new VM {Visual = MyGrid};
        }
    }
```

It is also possible to directly reference in the xaml using

```
 <VisualBrush Visual="{Binding ElementName=MyGrid}"/>
```